# SQL Server 2008 or above: Is there a clear criterion to determine whether I should or should not create an index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been reading "Microsoft SQL Server 2008: A Beginner's Guide" and came across the chapter on indices.  The book does a really good job of demonstrating *how* to create an index, but not *why* to create an index.

Nor have I been able to find any satisfactory explanations on the Internet. All the different search results I find are variations of a theme: "how to create an index."

My question is this: is there a clear criterion I can use to determine whether I *should* create an index? I have read so far that indices should be used intelligently, and that it might create overhead problems for tables with frequent inserts, updates, and deletes (which is true for my database).

Is the answer "it depends -- keep monitoring and adjusting" or is there a crisp criterion I can use to determine whether I should use indices?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: More of an art than a science,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no crisp criterion. There's just rules of thumb:

overall rule: If a field is used in a "decision context" (e.g. a `where`, `join`, `order by`, etc..., then it should be indexed.

After that, it comes down to usage cases. ie

rarely read, frequently modified - indexes may hurt. the overhead of keeping the indexes current will probably outweigh any benefits the indexes would give the relatively rare "read" operations.

frequently read, rarely modified - definitely. index maintenance overhead is only paid when the table is modified. since you modify rarely, the efficiency gains for the read operations will vastly outweigh the index overhead costs.

some reads/some updates - no way to tell - you'd have to benchmark your particular cases. a table with one index will have far less maintenance overhead than a table with hundreds of (overlapping?) indexes.

Comment: Rules of thumb are still helpful and a lot better than no guidance at all. Something like this should have been in the instruction manuals.